# Aggregate function for inet values in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have data such as:

```
addr
10.0.0.0/32
10.0.0.1/32
10.0.0.2/32
10.0.0.3/32
10.0.0.4/32
10.0.0.5/32
10.0.0.6/32
10.0.0.7/32
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
select agg_inets(addr) as supernets from addr_table
```

and get:

```
supernets
10.0.0.0/29
```

In another example, the data may not consist of consecutive addresses, in which case I would want to obtain a record set of CIDR ranges instead:

```
addr
10.0.0.0/32
10.0.0.4/32
10.0.0.5/32
10.0.0.6/32
10.0.0.7/32
```

Result:

```
10.0.0.0/32
10.0.0.4/30
```

It doesn't seem like there are any built-in functions to achieve this. Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 2):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3c8dc2a4c753652f6c15ef3911881d6d)

I found nothing built-in, but there is a function called `inet_merge(inet, inet)` ([Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html)) which can be used in a custom aggregation function:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE agg_inets (inet) (
    sfunc =  inet_merge,
    stype =  cidr,
    initcond = '10.0.0.0/32');
```

Comment: This looks good, although what is the significance of `initcond`? Do I have to know in advance the minimum value and ensure my inet addresses are consecutive? Can this work if all my records are not contiguous inet addresses by returning multiple minimally sized cidrs?

Comment: could you please add your use cases to your question, so we could check them. the initcond is necessary to tell the agg function what is the value which should be checked against the very first record. maybe there's a way to avoid this

Comment: You don't need the minimum of your data, you need the minimum of your network range. It works even if you don't have the 10.0.0.0  in your data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7e35521ec2c2d1ad4d522961886a514f

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the confusion - in my use case, it would be invalid to return a CIDR that implies some addresses were in the input record-set. I added another example!

Comment: Maybe this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aeddb949f86d14345381b5a579e55695